# Length of nested tuples

Tags: notation

Assume we have the following tuple of tuples: `S = ((1,2), (2,3,4,5), (4,5,6,7,8))`.

- There are three nested tuples. To write the length of `S` (the number of nested tuples), is it correct notation to write $\lvert S \rvert = 3$?
- How do one then write the notation for the length of a nested tuple? $\lvert S_i \rvert, i=1,2,..,\lvert S \rvert$? Examples:

  - $\lvert S_1 \rvert = 2$
  - $\lvert S_2 \rvert = 4$
  - $\lvert S_3 \rvert = 5$

Comment: Yes, and yes, what you wrote makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

This notation is not frequently used to denote the length of a tuple. Now it depends where you want to define "length of a tuple". In linear algebra, analysis,$\cdots$ we usually define a natural number $n\in\mathbb{N}$ to denote dimension of Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ or for a vector space $V$ we sometimes use $n=\dim(V)$